# Add service reference dynamically

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-client

Can we add a service reference dynamically to a project without using add reference in visual studio. Does Wsdl Import of metadata will help in achieving this goal can some one help me in dynamically loading and attaching  the service to project and use the client in wcf or suggest me a methodology in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework has a namespace dedicated to this called [System.ServiceModel.Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.aspx). From a high level you use a [DiscoveryClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.discoveryclient.aspx) which can locate services available for use.

To be able to locate services with the [DiscoveryClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.discoveryclient.aspx) the service info needs to be sent out through the [AnnouncementClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.announcementclient.aspx) class. This class allows a service to publish announcement messages. From the documentation:

> An announcement message contains information about the service such as its fully-qualified contract name, any scopes that the service is operating in as well as any custom metadata the service wants to send.

These classes should be everything you need to provide the plumbing for dynamic service discovery and usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to consume existing third party endpoints (services that are not under your control) there are at least two methods provided in the .NET framework.

1. [MetadataExchangeClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.metadataexchangeclient.aspx)
2. [MetadataResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.metadataresolver.aspx)

MetadataExchangeClient will connect to a MEX/wsdl endpoint and return back a collection of objects representing the service metadata.

MetadataResolver will return the configuration for a known service if you pass it the MEX/wsdl endpoint and the type to resolve. This allows you import the connection settings without having to specifiy it up front.

To see what else is available explore the [System.ServiceModel.Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195528.aspx) namespace. It has the two classes above plus others related to dynamic service resolution.

EDIT: This was able to retrieve Metadata for me:

```
MetadataExchangeClient client = new MetadataExchangeClient(
    new Uri("http://localhost:22948/Service1.svc?wsdl"),
    MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet);
var response = client.GetMetadata();
```

Comment: Hi Phil I have tried this resource online which uses service description class but i have an error when i import with the importer object it says missing argument name for some reason the link is [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhrubach/archive/2008/10/20/8623711.aspx)

Comment: I'll see if I can get a small example working tonight, I'll put it up on GitHub if I do.

Comment: HI Phil I found that the schema count was zero even though the wsdl file contains 6 schemas using the above example